# Using javascript with html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display some html after an if statement using some java script if its possible?

so for example

```
<script>
 if (count > 1) {
    <p1> some text here </p1>
} else {
    <p1> some text here</p1>
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure if there is an easier way to do this or not so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Very much possible using `DOM API`, not using the way you are trying...

Comment: You shouldn't look for an easier way, but for a way that actually works.

Comment: Found the duplicate via https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+dynamically+create+html